# installing pf-ring on Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, gcc, makefile, pf-ring

I'm trying to install pf-ring on mac os x yosemite 10.10.4. Doing what's written here: http://www.ntop.org/get-started/download/
so:

```
git clone https://github.com/ntop/PF_RING.git
cd PF_RING/kernel
```

so far so good, bu when doing "make" getting this:

```
$ make
make -C /lib/modules/14.4.0/build SUBDIRS=/usr/local/src/PF_RING/kernel EXTRA_CFLAGS='-I/usr/local/src/PF_RING/kernel -DGIT_REV="\"dev:b2a8f8a93b226e74428424e91a2ea3bd3148123d\""' modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/14.4.0/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:38: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What's the problem and how to solve it? Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a `/lib/modules/14.4.0/build` directory?

Comment: hmm... no... what should be there? there is no actually even `/lib/` directory

Comment: The `-C` argument to make is a directory for it to `cd` to before building. It is hard for make to function correctly if it gets a directory that doesn't exist, don't you think? You either need to install whatever you are missing that creates that directory (kernel pieces most likely) or figure out what you need to change/set/configure to have it use the correct directory in that location. Does `brew` or similar not have a pf-ring build you can use?

Answer (score 0):

Well I've asked the developers and they told me that pr_ring is not supported for OS X... Funny that there is no clear information about it on official website...

Answer (score 0):

PF_RING is a driver used for capturing packets and helps with active network traffic analysis. This driver can be installed better works if you have a 10G ethernet card on the box. Coming to macOS, yes you can install it by building it from the source. Please follow the steps from this link:  https://www.ntop.org/guides/pf_ring/get_started/git_installation.html.